# Mobile Safari -webkit-background-clip: text; and/or CSS-based text gradients in mobile safari

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-safari

I am getting nasty artifacts in mobile safari on both my iPhone 4S and a gen-2 iPad when trying to use -webkit css styles to get gradient text.

This is the relevant CSS, applied to a text element:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee 0%, #4a80e5 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#eee), to(#4a80e5));
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

It looks good in Chrome and Safari and fails gracefully in Firefox. It looks bad in mobile Safari.  You can see a live example at http://www.synchronautapp.com

On mobile safari, there are 1px borders around the styled elements. These borders come and go depending on how zoomed in the user is. Example here: http://synchronautapp.com/mkramer/IMG_0088.PNG

Googling didn't yield many similar issues. What causes this issue, and is there a workaround that keeps gradient text? Is there a pure CSS fallback plan for mobile webkit?

Comment: I've partially mitigated this effect by adding 1px black borders to these styles. It's an annoying hack that throws off pixel precision and it only works when I know the exact background color in advance. It's by no means a solution but it does make it look better than what was there before, so I'm doing this until I solve the issue.

Comment: 3 years later.. this drove me crazy, solved it finally by adding border and outline with the color of the background...

Comment: is still up to date

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
```

Comment: No apparent change from doing that. What is your thought process on that?

Comment: That helped solve one of my problems when dealing with resizing stuff and the edges of images being partial pixels that got blended incorrectly.